# auto pagination if using recyclerview inside NestedSrollView with Paging 3?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, android-paging-3, nestedrecyclerview

I'm using recyclerview inside nestedscrollview to scroll in the full page size but that ruined the pagination functionality because it auto loads all the pages without user scrolling.

here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View android:id="@+id/header_view"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/picked_up_rv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And I'm using Paging 3 for pagination

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.0"
```

Comment: I don't think that you can achieve that; once the the recyclerView is in a scroller view (the same direction), you'll lose the ability of recycling views

Comment: This is happening to me even when the ```RecyclerView``` is placed inside ```SwipeRefreshLayout```, which implements ```NestedScrollingParent & NestedScrollingChild```. Unable to find a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Paging3 library, you can define a `LoadStateAdapter` and attach it to your `PagingDataAdapter`, then you can attach footer and header views directly.

If you don't want to use the LoadStateAdapter, then you can create differents items for your `PagingDataAdapter` and then use item view type to retrieve what you want. With this method you get rid of your `NestedScrollView` which is useless since `RecyclerView` implements `ScrollingView`